# Is there a way to make objects take up less memory?

Tags: objects, memory-management

me and my friend are competing in a game making competition, (a competition where you compete with other people to make games), and in this competition the smaller the game size, the better you are rated(along with gameplay and such). I was wondering is there a way to make blender models lighter than they are. Blender's default preset with the cube, camera and light is around 400 kb is there a way to achieve even a smaller size, hopefully around 100k?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you have 1 triangle on 3d viewport and nothing more on the scene, and also when saving you select "COMPRESS" you will get to 96 kb.

Is this what you were looking for?
[image]

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: +1. It's also good to note that .blend files are not 3d model files but project files. They contain a lot of other stuff within allowing you to work on your objects. Like your materials, textures infos, any other objects, scenes, anims, blender's settings, tools used, brushes, If you want to reduce the file size of your models, may just export them alone.